# Can't get MAME to work for Ubuntu

Tags: games, emulation

I have been trying to set up a computer to use as an arcade cabinet computer, but I can't figure out how to set up MAME and ROMs on it. I have installed MAME with

```
sudo apt-get install mame mame-tools gnome-video-arcade sdlmame sdlmame-tools
```

and I have set up all of the folders and made sure that the .ini file points to the correct ROM path. I downloaded a ROM from freeRoms and put it in the Rom folder still in a zip file. I started up mame by

```
mame
```

in the terminal, but when I do that it says "No games found. Please check the rompath specified in the mame.ini file."
Could I please have help setting MAME up? I've done pretty much everything that I know how to do and it seems to me like I just have the wrong version of ROMS. I am open to re-installing everything if that would help. Thanks!

Comment: run `sudo /usr/games/mame`

Comment: Edit your question and add the ini file and `ls /path/to/roms`.

Comment: @DuminduMahawela: running an arcade emulator as `root`? Eww!

Answer (score 7):

***Ubuntu 13.04 onwards:***

The default path for user roms changed in MAME v0.147 to `~/mame/roms`, while settings are still at `~/.mame`, so before changing any ini files, please first try putting a known-to-work ROM zip there and test it.

When you run `mame` for the first time, `~/mame` or its `roms` subfolder may not be automatically created. So do this:

```
mkdir -p ~/mame/roms
```

Personally, instead of cluttering my top-level home dir and my small HOME partition with MAME and large ROMS, I usually choose to symlink it to my data partition ROMs folder:

```
ln -s /path/to/your/roms ~/mame/roms
```

You can also edit `~/.mame/mame.ini` (note the leading dot, it's a hidden dir!) and set the location of all MAME-related data paths, or edit the global config `/etc/mame/mame.ini` for all users, including changing the default top level data path `~/mame` or the settings path `~/.mame` to other paths.

Also it's worth noting that you don't need all those packages to install MAME. `sdlmame*` was a dummy transitional package and was removed in recent Ubuntu releases, `mame-tools` is not needed to run games, and `gnome-video-arcade` is just a GUI (that you're not using, considering you're starting MAME in the terminal). So `mame` is the only package you really need.

***Note for previous Ubuntu releases:***

The user paths for MAME-related dirs were changed in recent Ubuntu releases. For older releases such as 12.04, both settings and data (like ROMs) are inside the hidden `~/.mame`

After a *lot* of digging and researching, I've found out when and where such changes were made: the `.ini` location and default user paths are not an *upstream* setting, so it's not the MAME developers that set it, but rather configured by each distro.

It was changed in Debian, and later incorporated in Ubuntu, starting in MAME v0.146-5 and finished in v0.147-1.

From the [Debian Changelog](https://packages.debian.org/changelog:mame):

```
mame (0.146-5) unstable; urgency=low

  [ Cesare Falco ]
  * Replace -march with -mtune=generic gcc flag for compatibility issues
    with older CPUs (LP: #1063993)

  [ Emmanuel Kasper ]
  * Add support for parallel building using DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS
  * Reorganize default paths:
       $HOME/.mame for ini file and output files
       $HOME/mame for data search paths

 -- Emmanuel Kasper   Tue, 13 Nov 2012 22:54:27 +0100

mame (0.146-4) unstable; urgency=low
```

The relevant commits for such changes were

- 2012-10-26 - [9677867a63c6](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-games/mame.git/commit/?id=9677867a63c6e955df5604f33c88991660721082) - *Switch local folder to ~/mame (from ~/.mame)*
- 2012-11-14 - [824bc168084b](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-games/mame.git/commit/?id=824bc168084b39fa2306f61d154bb17aec952398) - *Edited config files; use personal non-hidden resources dirs.*

Comment: I've downloaded rom from this [link](http://www.mamedev.org/roms/) and keep `.zip` files in `~/.mame/rom` path. But MAME still showing **No games found**.

Comment: it is `~/.mame/roms`, not `~/.mame/rom`, Note the plural.

Comment: I have edited folder name. But still facing the same problem.

Comment: it's `mame`, not `.mame`, without the dot. But you can change it in /etc/mame/mame.ini

Comment: @LuisSieira It seems this was changed from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04, thanks for pointing it out! I've made a *major* edit to update all info, including my own research, check it out

Comment: @Scotia웃 I've updated for Ubuntu 14.04, maybe the new info will solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Mame is just the emulator - now you need to find ROMs for the games you would like to play and put them in `~/mame/roms` (create the directory if it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 1):

From : http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/how-to-install-mame-multiple-arcade.html

2. MAME Configuration

Start now MAME with this command so that a hidden folder (.mame) is created in your home directory which will contain all emulator settings:

mame

You can now close the emulator. Run this command to create the configuration file for MAME:

cd ~/.mame && mame -cc

The "mame.ini" file will be created in the ~/.mame folder. Edit now this file with this command:

gedit ~/.mame/mame.ini

For Linux Mint:

pluma ~/.mame/mame.ini

In "rompath", you can set your own ROM directory path or leave default paths:

Next, create the following directories in the ~/.mame folder:

```
nvram
sta
roms
memcard
inp
comments
snap
diff
```

You can create them all with this command:

mkdir  ~/.mame/nvram memcard roms inp comments sta snap diff

You can access the rom folder with this command to place your downloaded roms in:

nautilus ~/.mame/roms

As for player controls, you can easily configure them from the main interface of MAME (Configure General Inputs):

Comment: I would not recommend this blog post: It says "14.04 and older" but yet it contains outdated information, incorrect commands, and, it suggests installing MAME from an unofficial PPA instead of using the trusted repositories.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 except to get the desktop icon to work, you have to create a `mame.ini` in your home directory with the command `mame -cc`. Then `gedit ~/mame.ini` and change all the directories above to `.mame/nvram` `.mame/sta` `.mame/roms` ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [to this guide](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/how-to-install-mame-multiple-arcade.html) to set up mame
Roms should be put in the roms directory specified in the file mame.ini

Note that if you need Metal Slug to work (as most of the users downloaded mame just for that game) you need to include the latest rom of neogeo and put it in the rom directory.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install mame
```

After Launching Mame "Configure Options" --> "Configure Directories" --> "ROM" --> "Add Folder"
And also there are default folders listed.

In ubuntu 18.04