# Mame refuses to start after following advice given elsewhere

Tags: mame

It's my first time using MAME. When I start it, I get the classic newbie error message:

> No games found. Please check the rompath specified in the mame.ini file.
>
> If this is your first time using mame, please see the config.txt file in the docs directory for information on configuring MAME.

(I can't for the life of me find that file.) But I have set up my environment exactly as [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398346/cant-get-mame-to-work-for-ubuntu) describes. In my home directory, in both `mame` and `.mame`, I have this directory structure:

```
cfg/
comments/
diff/
inp/
memcard/
nvram/
roms/
snap/
sta/
mame.ini
```

And in the `roms` folder in both of the two parent directories I have all my ROMs, in both zipped and unzipped form. MAME still refuses to work.

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: How did you install MAME?

Comment: @edwinksl Through the official repositories.

Comment: Hmm, okay. `config.txt` is definitely easy to find if you download and extract the tarball, but I am not sure where it would be if you installed MAME using `apt`. Can you try `type -a mame` and tell me what it says?

Comment: @edwinksl `mame is /usr/games/mame`

Comment: From http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/mame/filelist, `config.txt` is in `/usr/share/doc/mame`. Take a look there and see what `config.txt` says about configuring MAME.